# Project wide "set_option autoImplicit false" in Lean 4

Tags: lean4

I want to turn off the `autoImplicit` option for a whole [lake](https://github.com/leanprover/lake) project. Could I achieve that in `lakefile.lean`? The options `moreLeanArgs`, `moreLeancArgs`, and `moreLinkArgs` don't seem to concern `set_option`; am I mistaken?

Comment: `moreLeanArgs := #["-DautoImplicit=false"]` works for me, but you need (probably) also add `-DautoImplicit=false` to the Lean’s “Server Args” in your editor (e.g. VSCode).

Comment: @siegment `"lean4.serverArgs": ["-DautoImplicit=false"]` in `.vscode/settings.json` did the trick. Thanks a lot. Please post it as an answer. However, the setting is not shared between `lake` and the Lean4 VSCode extension. `moreLeanArgs := #["-DautoImplicit=false"]` in the lake only applies to lake.

Comment: >However, the setting is not shared between lake and the Lean4 VSCode extension<

Yes, that’s why I wrote about editor settings.

Comment: @siegment I understand. I was trying to further ask if there was a way to unify the settings?

Comment: @siegment Unfortunately, `"lean4.serverArgs": ["-DautoImplicit=false"]` will affect the live parsing of the prelude. Is there a way for the language server to apply global options at the project/library granularity?

Comment: `moreServerArgs := #["-DautoImplicit=false"]` seems to work project-wide. So you may write `def leanArgs := #["-DautoImplicit=false"]` and then `package MyPackage { moreServerArgs := leanArgs, moreLeanArgs := leanArgs }` to avoid duplication.

Comment: @siegment `moreServerArgs` indeed gets picked up by the language server and gets applied at project/library scope without affecting the live-parsing of the prelude. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moreLeanArgs := #["-DautoImplicit=false"]` works for me, but you need (probably) also add `-DautoImplicit=false` to the Lean’s “Server Args” in your editor (e.g. VSCode).

*(Reposted as answer.)*